# Sbt- Passing a project and it's dependencies as dependency in another project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project A which has all spark and hadoop dependencies. Another project B has been created which requires the code of project A to execute as well as it's dependencies.
The reason for having project A and its dependencies is because the project B can be imagined as an extension of Project A with some additional functionality and also code reusability purposes. The version of scala for both the projects will be the same.

Basically
Project B Dependencies = (Project A / Project A Dependencies)

Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Edit : The project A is published to an artifactory and Project B is supposed to use it and It's dependencies as libraries to work.
If unmanaged jars method is used this works fine since the jars are present with the dependencies as well, but having these as libraries from an artifactory does not produce the dependencies only the project code

Comment: You can use an **sbt** multi-module setup and make module `B` depend on module `A` - Another approach is to publish project `A` as a library.

Comment: I did publish project A as a library, and imported it in project B but it didn't import the dependencies of project A.

Comment: @sa'kage The dependencies are transitively imported by default: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Automatic+Dependency+Management

Comment: Nope, again as I said, other than the original code of project A no dependencies are getting imported in project B and have to be defined seperately in dependency.scala.

Comment: @sa'kage you would need to share the original code or create a reproducible example because many of us have published multiple libraries and transitive dependencies have always worked out of the box.

Comment: Make sure you don't have `Provided` in the dependencies of your project A. But as mentioned before, it would be nice to see the SBT set-up to understand the problem.

Comment: @JavierMontón This `Provided` is precisely why it was not working as expected. Write this as an answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have `% Provided` at the end of your dependencies in project A, it is used to specify that you will provide the dependencies manually, so they are not being included.